# How can events be mathematically modeled?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, partial-derivative

I would like to know, in general, how events can be modeled by differential equations. Recently, I have learned how to solve some PDEs, but it is not enough. I want to know how the Heat Equation was "created", for example.

Let's suppose the following scenario:

I want to know the volume of blood ($b$) that flows through my veins depending on time ($t$), and how fast my heart beats ($h$). How could I model this? Just throw some partial derivatives and constants ($k_n$) and that's it? For example,

$$\partial^2_b = 2t \partial_t + \partial_h + k_0 + error$$

I would really appreciate anything as an answer, either a general or particular explanation.

Thanks.

Comment: The first page here provides a physical derivation of the heat equation using laws of physics and a little calculus as an example of how a PDE was “created”: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-303-linear-partial-differential-equations-fall-2006/lecture-notes/heateqni.pdf any other PDE that models a physical or biological system will more or less require a derivation based informed by that discipline’s theory. Often similar or the same equations can model separate things by changing interpretation or form of parameters (see predator prey models in biology, epidemiology, and economics)

Comment: You need to make some reasonable assumptions about how various physical quantities are related to each other. A great example is Newton's "law" of cooling. Suppose that the temperature of an object (like a cup of coffee) at time $t$ is $T(t)$, and the ambient temperature in the room is $T_0$. It does not seem too far off the mark to imagine that the rate of change of the temperature might be proportional to the difference between the ambient temperature and the temperature of the object. In other words, $T'(t) = k(T_0 - T(t))$, for some constant $k$.  That's Newton's model of cooling.

Comment: I got it! Thanks for your answers.